# Error in the page

Tags: php, android, web-services

I am creating a php script for my android application which will authenticate the user. In the  script the following error is occurring:

> Connected Welcome You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '‘ AND Password = ‘' at line 1

```
query :- $query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE Username = ‘$un’ AND Password = ‘$pw’";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());;
```

Comment: You'll need to show a little more code than that - it looks like $un isn't being set to what you think it is. Try outputting $query to the screen to seen what SQL you're actually generating.

Answer (score 5):

The quotes you are using appear to be different. You should use the ascii single quote character on either side of your values.

```
query :- $query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE Username = '$un' AND Password = '$pw'";
```

Also ensure the right values are present within `$un` and `$pw`